# Fish shell, nvm, is telling me that node and npm are "currently not installed" but they are

Tags: node.js, npm, fish, nvm, macos-big-sur

I'm having a problem with npm and node, using the fish shell, following a recent update of fish, fisher, bass and nvm on OS X Big Sur.

**$ node -v**

```
type: Invalid combination of options
Fish nvm: 'node' is currently not installed, try running npm i -g node
```

**$ npm -v**

```
type: Invalid combination of options
Fish nvm: 'npm' is currently not installed, try running npm i -g npm
```

NVM seems to be working fine:

**$ nvm list**

```
->     v10.16.0
        v12.4.0
       v12.16.1
       v13.11.0
       v14.16.0
         system
default -> 10.16.0 (-> v10.16.0)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> v14.16.0) (default)
stable -> 14.16 (-> v14.16.0) (default)
lts/* -> lts/fermium (-> v14.16.0)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.0 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.21.0 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.16.0
```

It successfully switches node versions.

**$ nvm use v14**
`Now using node v14.16.0 (npm v6.14.11)`

**$ which node**
`/Users/brianfogel/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node`

**$ which npm**
`/Users/brianfogel/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/npm`

For additional context here are some other things that might be helpful to show:

**$ fish --version**
`fish, version 3.2.0`

**$ fisher --version**
`fisher, version 4.2.0`

**$ nvm -v**
`0.37.2`

**$ cat ~/.config/fish/functions/node.fish**

```
function node -d "Server-side JavaScript runtime" -w node
  __nvm_run "node" $argv
end
```

**$ cat ~/.config/fish/functions/npm.fish**

```
function npm -d "node package manager" -w npm
  __nvm_run "npm" $argv
end
```

**$ cat ~/.config/fish/functions/nvm.fish**

```
function nvm
  if not type -q bass
    echo 'Bass is not installed please install it running fisher edc/bass'
    return
  end
  set -q NVM_DIR; or set -gx NVM_DIR ~/.nvm
  set -q nvm_prefix; or set -gx nvm_prefix $NVM_DIR
  
  bass source $nvm_prefix/nvm.sh --no-use ';' nvm $argv

  set bstatus $status

  if test $bstatus -gt 0
    return $bstatus
  end

  if test (count $argv) -lt 1
    return 0
  end

  if test $argv[1] = "use"; or test $argv[1] = "install"
    set -g NVM_HAS_RUN 1
  end
end
```

**$ cat /usr/local/bin/node**

```
#! /usr/bin/env fish
__nvm_run "node" $argv
```

**$ cat /usr/local/bin/npm**

```
#!/usr/bin/env fish
__nvm_run "npm" $argv
```

**$ $ set --show fish_user_paths**

```
$fish_user_paths: set in global scope, unexported, with 10 elements
$fish_user_paths[1]: |/Users/brianfogel/.pub-cache/bin|
$fish_user_paths[2]: |/Users/brianfogel/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/bin|
$fish_user_paths[3]: |/Users/brianfogel/flutter/flutter/bin|
$fish_user_paths[4]: |/usr/local/sbin|
$fish_user_paths[5]: |/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin|
$fish_user_paths[6]: |/Users/brianfogel/.npm-global/bin|
$fish_user_paths[7]: |/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.4_1/bin|
$fish_user_paths[8]: |/usr/local/sbin|
$fish_user_paths[9]: |/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin|
$fish_user_paths[10]: |/Users/brianfogel/.yarn/bin|
$fish_user_paths: set in universal scope, unexported, with 4 elements
$fish_user_paths[1]: |/Users/brianfogel/.npm-global/bin|
$fish_user_paths[2]: |/usr/local/sbin|
$fish_user_paths[3]: |/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin|
$fish_user_paths[4]: |/Users/brianfogel/.yarn/bin|
```

Comment: This is https://github.com/FabioAntunes/fish-nvm/issues/55, should be fixed in the newest release of that plugin

Comment: Yes, solved by https://github.com/FabioAntunes/fish-nvm/releases/tag/1.4.2

Comment: @faho If you turn that into a real answer, you have earned my upvote!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://github.com/FabioAntunes/fish-nvm has been updated. Installing or updating the plugin fixes the problem.